# How to search for strings containing square brackets and a specific number of chars with the LIKE operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-like

I would like to tell to the LIKE operator in a SELECT query in SQL Server2008R2 to search for strings containing strings like these

```
[can]
[eur]
[usd]
```

basically

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION
FROM TABLE
WHERE 
  DESCRIPTION contains two square brakets and there are three chars in the square brackets
```

Somehow these would be returned results

```
Freddie Young [FRY] 
Micheal Norton [MIN]
```

but those not

```
Laura Cunningham [LC]
Marc Lizard (MAL)
```

i imagine RegEx wih CLR is an option, but i would like to peform this with a simple query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. Note the use of the ESCAPE clause to escape the [ and ] characters.

```
WITH cte(value)
as
(
 SELECT 'Freddie Young [FRY]' 
  Union
 SELECT 'Micheal Norton [MIN]'
  Union
 SELECT 'Laura Cunningham [LC]'
  Union
 SELECT 'Marc Lizard (MAL)')
 Select * 
   FROM cte
  Where value like '%![[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]!]%' escape '!'
```

A version without escaping is below. To find an opening square bracket, you need to enclose it in square brackets. To find a closing square bracket, just use the character. No enclosing is required.

```
WITH cte(value)
AS
(
 SELECT 'Freddie Young [FRY]' 
  UNION
 SELECT 'Micheal Norton [MIN]'
  UNION
 SELECT 'Laura Cunningham [LC]'
  UNION
 SELECT 'Marc Lizard (MAL)'
 )
 SELECT * 
 FROM cte
 WHERE value like '%[[][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]]%'
```

[MSDN Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: THanks a lot. Extremly clear and useful.I will use the one with escape since it seems more readable to me